# onSelect function on a select element doesn't get called in Blazor

Tags: html, .net, api, asynchronous, blazor

I'm currently working on an application that displays some movies. I have an API that successfully retrieves the movies and also has the option to get movies by a specific genre. For that I've created a Select element with the different genres dynamically loaded in. When one of the genres is clicked I want to update the movies by using the API to only get the movies in the selected genre.

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I select an option. Please note that I have confirmed that the API calls work so it has to be something in this code.
This is the HTML-element:

```
<div class="content px-sm-3">
    <select>
        <option onselect="async () => await changeMoviesByGenre('None')" value="None">None</option>
        @foreach (var genre in genres)
        {
            <option value=@genre onselect="async () => await changeMoviesByGenre(genre)">@genre</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

and this is the function that should be called:

```
private async Task changeMoviesByGenre(string genre) {
        if (genre == "None") {
            movies = await MovieClient.Movies.GetAll();
        }

        else {
            movies = await MovieClient.Movies.GetAllMoviesByGenre(genre);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnSelect` isn't what you think it is.  It's triggered when you select text in an `Input` element.

The simpler way (as you have covered in answering your answer and I've included as a full working page for completeness in the answer) is:

```
@page "/Test"

<div class="content px-sm-3 m-2">
    <select @onchange="OnChange">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        @foreach (var genre in genres)
        {
            <option value="@genre">@genre</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div class="m-2">Selected: @SelectedGenre</div>

@code {

    private List<string> genres
        => new List<string>() { "Rock", "Folk", "Blues", "Pop" };

    private string SelectedGenre = string.Empty;

    private async Task OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = e.Value.ToString();
        SelectedGenre = "Getting it, just wait!!!";
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        if (selected.Equals("None", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            this.SelectedGenre = "Give it another Go!";
        else
            this.SelectedGenre = selected;
    }
}
```

@Onxxxx (such as @OnChange and @OnClick) are UI events.  They are run by the UI process before re-rendering on the component.  A Task event handler is run by the UI and awaits the `Task` before updating the UI.  A void event handler is started by the UI process, and if/when it yields updates the UI (a lot more complicated and unpredictable).  You can use these code patterns dependant on your needs:

```
async void MyEventHander() {}` //for handlers that need to do async work and you don't need the UI process to wait on the completion of the handler.
async Task MyEventHander() {}` //for handlers that need to complete before re-rendering.
void MyEventHander() {}` //for handlers with no async work.
```

In my example I've added `await Task.Delay(1000);` to simulate an async database call so I can declare the handler as `async`.

Note:

1. `e` in `OnChange` is an object, so you can cast it to what you are expecting.
2. None is already selected on initialization, so if you select it first, there's no `OnChange` because nothing has changed.

See [Ms Docs - Blazor Event Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling).

Comment: I like this answer.  However, I think `async Task` is recommended.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Interesting point, I've read conflicted recommendations, so  I followed the source code trail in the ASPNetCore Repo back from the `EventCallbackFactory`.  You see `InvokeAsync` back to `EventCallbackWorkItem` where it switches to `Invoke`, returning a `Task.Completed`. So deep down it looks like it sinks it.  If you're working with a Component `EventCallback` with await then yes it is good practice.  Looks like horses for courses.

Comment: Nice sleuthing.  Now let me follow the source code back to "horses for courses."  :D

Comment: Thank you for explaining why this works and my initial code doesn't!
The reason that I'm using an async/await with a Task is that otherwise the UI doesn't update. I forgot where I found that but apparently the method to update the UI doesn't get called when using an async void? So I ran into the problem that my function would be called but the list wouldn't update, that's why I'm using async/await in combination with a Task.

Comment: @Bram I've updated the answer to fit more closely with your question.  Good coding.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the problem somehow.
If you're having the same problem that I had, I fixed it by using this [example](https://blazor-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/49947790/blazor-onchange-event-with-select-dropdown) I do not know why it works, but it does.

I'm not using the values from the foreach but instead I'm now using the ChangedEventArgs parameters. I also set the onchange to the Select element and not the Options elements. This is how my code now looks:

```
<div class="content px-sm-3">
    <select @onchange=@changeMovies>
        <option value="None"> None </option>
        @foreach (var genre in genres) {
            <option value=@genre> @genre </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

and this is the new function that gets called (please note that this has to be a task otherwise the page won't get updated)

```
 private async Task changeMovies(ChangeEventArgs e) {
        string selectedGenre = e.Value.ToString();
        if (selectedGenre == "None") {
            movies = await MovieClient.Movies.GetAll();
        }
        else {
            movies = await MovieClient.Movies.GetAllMoviesByGenre(selectedGenre);
        }
    }
```